# SSRS weekly parameter not working

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, report, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to add a weekly parameter into my `SSRS` report,

I have been using

```
=DateAdd("d",-7, Today)
```

and also

```
=DateAdd("ww",-1, Today)
```

Neither bring up the dates that I need to display there are dates from the `01/01/2014` showing up on the report.

Is there something else that needs adding into the report for this parameter to work？
I need to show all of the previous weeks data from the day the report is processed but it is showing dates that go before last Monday.

Comment: Hi what you need show? 01/01/2014? that format?

Comment: I need to show last weeks data but it is showing the full months data.

Comment: can you give an example to understand you better please

Comment: I need the date range from 27/01/2014 until 02/02/2014 to show in the report. 

The date parameter is not working on the report preview

Comment: Try: DATEADD(DAY,-7,Today)

Comment: That is showing me an error :(

Comment: this happen maybe because your parameter isn't date type go to propertys from your parameter and change String for Date

Comment: I need to show all of the previous weeks data from the day the report is processed but it is showing dates that go before last monday.

Comment: Do I need to add anything into the dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you date for of the previous week.

```
=DATEDIFF(WEEK,1,[date_col])
```

Hope this is what you want. Your question is unclear. Add the dataset query & the report screenshot here if possible.